# PHP AES encryption charset issue

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, aes

I want to be able to retrieve data from server B, in an encrypted form, and decrypt it locally on server A.

On server A, I have a page with form inputs for a key value and a filename value, and the form posts to the same page. Once the values are inputted, I take the filename value and I build an `fopen` string to Server B, read the file's text via `fgets`, and return it to the [AES class](http://www.phpaes.com), using the key value to decrypt it.

The form page on server A is utf-8 encoded by means of a `meta charset` tag. The file on server B is a utf-8 encoded txt file.

When just dealing with local values (not using the form or anything), everything works fine:

```
$original = "this is my string";
$original_encrypted = $aes->encrypt($original);
$return = "<p>Original, encrypted: ".$original_encrypted."</p>";
$return.= "<p>Original: ".$aes->decrypt($original_encrypted)."</p>";
echo  $return;

//prints:
Original, encrypted: ѶIQ��SҨ�$��� ,O�������~ f
Original: this is my string
```

If, however, I take that encrypted string `ѶIQ��SҨ�$��� ,O�������~ f` and place it in my txt file on server B:

```
function retrieve_data($filename) {
    //... some validation
    $file=fopen("http://serverB/authorisation/logs/$filename.txt","r");
        while (($line = fgets($file)) !== false) {
            $parts.=stripslashes(trim($line));
        }
    fclose($file);
    return $parts;
}

//... some key validation
$z = "A3C56F83425746B4D62F984".$key; // 256-bit key
$aes = new AES($z);

$data = retrieve_data(stripslashes(trim($_POST['filename'])));
$return = "<p>Remote, Encrypted, Text: ".$data."</p>";
$return.= "<p>Now Plain Text: ".$aes->decrypt($data)."</p>";
echo $return;

//prints:
Remote, Encrypted, Text: ѶIQ��SҨ�$��� ,O�������~ f

Now Plain Text: B\�%;�`��]��\mb���q�)� �E�������l�����P�V+c�Ah�@ƶ>yq
```

Why would this be so? Given the same encrypted string, I'm getting two different outputs. I can only imagine there is some issue with the charset that is changing values somewhere along the way.

If I change my form page's encryption to `ISO-8859-1`, the encrypted string becomes `Ñ¶IQ’°SÒ¨á$«Îà ,OþÆÿ‡ÿè~ f`. When I try to change the encoding of the remote txt file to ISO, and copy this string there, cPanel tells me that some of the characters are incompatible with ISO and boots me back to UTF-8. I then tried leaving serverA as ISO, but casting `mb_convert_encoding` or `utf8-encode` / `utf8-decode` on the incoming / outgoing data, but no working result. Any ideas?

Comment: Since the encrypted data on both servers are the same, it would seem to me that your not using the right key to either encrypt or decrypt the data.

Comment: Are you "placing" the encrypted string by literally copy and pasting it into the file as garbage?

Comment: @deceze Yep - I'm placing it just by literally copying and placing as garbage. You think I should write to the file?

Comment: @JesperBunnyJensen Well, I'm using the same key right now to encrypt & decrypt both the local and remote data concurrently, and both return different values even when given the same initial data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encrypted string is pseudo-random binary noise. It has no meaning as visible characters, because it doesn't represent any text encoding. If you display the string as characters, you'll get some random garbage which may or may not be missing individual bytes or have altered characters. If you copy and paste this into another file, there's no guarantee you're getting the same binary data back.

Don't treat the encrypted string as a readable piece of text. Instead write it into a file, copy that file and don't touch it. If you need the binary data as a copy-and-pasteable string, `base64_encode` it.

Comment: Awesome - didn't realise the detail involved I guess. Works now - tyvm!